# Where or how can I get more information about an error 500?

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-core

I have managed to publish an asp.net-5 app on a server with IIS, but now I get a 500 Internal Server Error. How can I get more information on what's wrong ?

In the wwwroot/web.config, I have added:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

I have also temporarily changed the Startup to show errors like in development by commenting out the `if (env.IsEnvironment("Development"))` around the

```
app.UseBrowserLink();
app.UseErrorPage(ErrorPageOptions.ShowAll);
app.UseDatabaseErrorPage(DatabaseErrorPageOptions.ShowAll);
```

I also set the Configuration to 'Debug' in the publish wizard, but I still get the error 500 page without further information.

How can I make it display the stack trace and all other debug informations ?
(I also tried to look for the error in the Windows logs but couldn't find anything)

Answer (score 0):

I could get the trace by viewing the page from within the server.

So it actually behaves like when setting the `<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">` in asp.net < 5. I still wonder how to allow remote hosts to view trace in asp.net-5...